# When adding a product to cart on Chrome and Firefox - it adds the quantity of 1 but on IE 11 and Safari 5.1.7 it adds quantity of 2

Tags: checkout

Magento 1.9.1.0
Porto Theme

I just came across something really interesting. When I go through the order process in Chrome or Firefox - everything works the way I would expect --) products get added with quantity of 1. If I use IE 11 or Safari (5.1.7) - it adds all products twice (with the quantity of 2). Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when the add to cart button is a sumbit button and has an `onclick` event on it that submits the form.
This makes the form submit twice on IE. Not sure about IE 11, but it used to happen on IE 9 and lower.

Comment: What is the solution to this? Is this a problem with the Porto theme you think?

Comment: I don't know how the porto theme looks like. You can check id this is the case. The solution would be to make the add to cart button a simple button instead if submit.